# Get id of dynamically generated button in Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've a table with a list of object and in every row I've dynamically generated button to delete the row.

how to get in `@{ c#  }`  the id of the pressed button?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < BL.SNG.GetListLen(); i++)
{
    <form method="post"
          action="">
        <input type="submit"
               value="Delete @i"
               id="@i"
               onclick="button_click(this.id)" />
    </form>
    </td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'delete'? Remove it from displaying on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the id on the wrong element. Since the loop creates a new form element and a new button on each iteration. the id should be assigned to the form element itself. I assume button_click refers to some JavaScript function defined elsewhere.

Note that it is discouraged to attach event handlers to elements in the html markup portion of your page. You should generally add them from JavaScript. Like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")
.forEach( addEventListener("click", function (...) { });
```

Sorry, I just noticed your comment about deleting the row represented from the database.
You could use the submit action of the form itself to do that as well.

Comment: @user3170524, You can use `this.id`

Comment: the button doesn't need an id it just needs a function which refers to the id of the form. `function(id){ document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none"; }`

Comment: Also, i think this is a syntax error value="Delete @i" should be value = @("Delete " + i)

Comment: the delete in database is working well, but i don't know how to take the number of id an put it in var (index):

if(ispost){  bool inserted = BL.deleteanuser(index);}  replacing with a number works well.

Comment: I'm confused that function in your comment doesn't look like C# or JavaScript

Comment: I'm still learning the ropes with Razor and MVC 5 myself. I do think this will help you though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-9 it uses the html helpers and eschews direct JavaScript.